# Can we understand from where a http request is coming or redirecting?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm seeing my website's Transfer Logs and I think someone is trying to eat my bandwidth and take my website down...
There are so many http requests in POST method that were called in seconds and all of them call a link that doesn't exist on my site!

There are up to 10 requests per second to a link similar to this:

```
http://example.com/im/eating/you?a=123&b=456
```

Is there any way I can get from where these requests are coming from?
Or from where these requests are redirecting to my site?
And I know how to stop the attack but I specifically want to who is attacking me.. you know so that's why I like to know where these requests are coming from.

I have found this:
http://www.wheregoes.com/

But what this system does is that if we provide it a URL, then it lets us know that the URL redirected to where... But I like the opposite somehow! I wanna know the URL is coming from where?

Comment: Yes, you can, there are many ways to do it in php including $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]

Comment: @Starkeen - He said the file requested doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check your [Apache Access Logs](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache%20access%20logs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). They should contain info about where the requests are coming from.

Or, if you're concerned specifically about the request going to the page that doesn't exist, you could make that page, and do some logging of the `$_SERVER` vars.

Chances are though that it's not an attack, because if they wanted to take your site down, they would eat more bandwidth by requesting a page that does exists.

Comment: Yes I know, in my access log each of them coming from different IP addresses... I don't care about the IP address and the user-agent but I wanna find out from which domain and website these are coming! Because you know, I assume these requests are going somewhere else and that website is redirecting them to me... I wanna know who is redirecting me the requests.

Comment: If the IP addresses are servers then you can just copy them into your browser to see what website they are. If not, then you know they are users and someone has mis-typed a link.

Comment: Yes in that way we can get where the requests are coming from. But that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I don't know if I could express myself clearly or not. But here's the thing I'd like to know about: I wanna specifically find out whether the request first went to another website and then that website redirected it to me? Or the request directly came to me without any mediator at the middle of the way?

Comment: @Ali - you say the page being requested doesn't exist, right? so then create it and log all the $_SERVER variables. If that info is available it will be in there.